# Tensorflow text_generation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through the code
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation

When I arrive at the line the following error is produced.

```
 sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions[0], num_samples=1)
 sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()
```

Error

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in

```
----> 1 sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions[0], num_samples=1)
2 sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.random' has no attribute 'categorical'
```

**System information**
- TensorFlow version: 1.12 Jupyter NoteBooks on Ubuntu

Any pointers for what could be missing? I'm wondering if there is an import missing?

Comment: You can now update to `tf 2.0`. This issue is fixed in 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tf.random.categorical probably has been changed to tf.random.multinomial, assuming example_batch_predictions are logits:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/multinomial

Comment: Looks like `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy` can be replaced by `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. So `return tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)`.